# Need a .bat file to create a .csv output file of current dir, it's sub dirs and file names without file extensions

Tags: batch-file, csv

The .csv file needs to have all path segments in separate cells

From this:

```
dir *.mp3 *.flac /b /s /ON | sort > tracklist.csv

Z:\Audio\Music\Boston\1976\Boston\01 - More Than A Feeling.mp3
```

To This:

```
Z | Audio | Music | Boston | 1976 | Boston | 01 - More Than A Feeling
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible with regular batch files (or at least quite complicated). It will probably be easier doing it using PowerShell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is not beautiful, but should work.

It won't work with very long paths (but can be adapted with the number of tokens)

I used comma as separator, but you can also use `|` : just replace the commas in `set "line=...` with `^|`. Also in `if "%line:~-1%"=="^|" ...`

```
@echo off
(for /f "tokens=1-20 delims=:\." %%a in ( 'dir *.mp3 *.flac /b /s /ON ^| sort' ) do (
  set "line=%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f,%%g,%%h,%%i,%%j,%%k,%%l,%%m,%%n,%%o,%%p,%%q%%r,%%s,%%t"
  call :loop :: removing trailing separators
)) > tracklist.csv
exit /b

:loop :: remove trailing separators and extensions
  if "%line:~-1%"=="," set "line=%line:~0,-1%" && goto :loop
  set "line=%line:,mp3=%"
  set "line=%line:,flac=%"
  echo %line%
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited to add filters to remove the mp3/flac file extensions.

This should work and uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
dir *.mp3 *.flac /b /s /a-d | sort |repl ":" "" |repl "\..{3,4}$" "" |repl "\\" " | "  > tracklist.csv
```